# django-admin dose not create project

Tags: django

I'm running django 2.0.7 on a verual envirment python3 and when i run **django-admin startproject trydjango1 . ** the following error occers can you please help me to solve this problem

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\TG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in *run_module_as_main
return *run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\TG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\Scripts\django-admin.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init**.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management_*init**.py", line 365, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\startproject.py", line 20, in handle
super().handle('project', project_name, target, **options)
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\templates.py", line 117, in handle
django.setup()
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django_*init*_.py", line 16, in setup
from django.urls import set_script_prefix
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\urls_*init*_.py", line 1, in 
from .base import (
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 8, in 
from .exceptions import NoReverseMatch, Resolver404
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\urls\exceptions.py", line 1, in 
from django.http import Http404
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\http_*init*_.py", line 5, in 
from django.http.response import (
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\http\response.py", line 13, in 
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers_*init*_.py", line 23, in 
from django.core.serializers.base import SerializerDoesNotExist
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\core\serializers\base.py", line 6, in 
from django.db import models
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models_*init*_.py", line 3, in 
from django.db.models.aggregates import *  # NOQA
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\aggregates.py", line 5, in 
from django.db.models.expressions import Case, Func, Star, When
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 486, in 
class TemporalSubtraction(CombinedExpression):
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\expressions.py", line 487, in TemporalSubtraction
output_field = fields.DurationField()
File "D:\django-projects\Test1\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields_*init*_.py", line 155, in **init**
if isinstance(choices, collections.Iterator):
AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterator'

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try different python or/and django version, because both are not compatible with each other.

Try upgrading Django to `2.2.28` version, or run project under `python 3.6` (or even lower ver).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should install a newer version of django. It could be that some packages in the version of django you are using are not supported by python 3. I suggest you upgrade to django 3+